Why does dropshadow on a button in JavaFX not work the same as on a pane
See this part of a screen cap.

The first dropshadow I added to this FXML page was for the white panes, I used
-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(16, 40, 123, 0.2), 0px, 0px, 4px, 4px);

in css and it works like we'd want it to
Then I copied the same dropshadow to the buttons (even though we might want to adjust the thickness or color one way or the other) and somehow the dropshadow now also shadows the button itself. The color of the upper button should be white, just as the text on the lower button, but those css-settings now seem to be overruled by the dropshadow which should only be performed outside the buttons, not within its borders
Is this some kind of bug or some configuration or setting that can fix this?
Java 21 (openjdk-21.0.0)
Code for MRE, starting with pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <groupId>nl.mre</groupId>
  <artifactId>MRE</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
    <spring.boot.version>3.2.3</spring.boot.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

SpringBootApp.java
package nl.mre;

import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(JavaFXApplication.class, args);
    }
}

JavaFXApplication.java
package nl.mre;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {
    private Parent rootNode;

    private Stage mainStage;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext mainContext = SpringApplication.run(JavaFXApplication.class);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Mre.fxml"));
            loader.setControllerFactory(mainContext::getBean);
            try {
                rootNode = loader.load();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //no logging in MRE
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        mainStage = primaryStage;
        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
        mainStage.setResizable(false);
        mainStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        mainStage.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

/resources/fxml/Mre.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="648.0" prefWidth="1152.0" stylesheets="@../css/application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21">
    <center>
        <Pane prefHeight="600" prefWidth="1152.0" styleClass="pane-background">
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="390.0" styleClass="label-big-and-bold" text="Nieuw" />
            <Pane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="176.0" prefHeight="264.0" prefWidth="390.0" styleClass="pane-white">
                <TextField alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="350.0" styleClass="textfield" />
                <Label layoutX="24.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="110.0" styleClass="label-small" text="A *" textAlignment="RIGHT" />
                <TextField alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="350.0" styleClass="textfield" />
                <Label layoutX="24.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="140.0" styleClass="label-small" text="B *" />
                <Button disable="true" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="135.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="180.0" styleClass="button-audio" text="ALLEEN AUDIO" />
                <Region layoutX="115.0" layoutY="145.0" opacity="0.4" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="24.0" styleClass="region-audio" />
                <Button disable="true" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="195.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="180.0" styleClass="button-video" text="AUDIO EN VIDEO" />
                <Region layoutX="115.0" layoutY="209.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="24.0" styleClass="region-video" />
            </Pane>
        </Pane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>

/resources/css/application.css
.button-primary, .button-agree, .button-login, .button-start, .button-stop, .button-video {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(16, 40, 123, 0.2), 0px, 0px, 4px, 4px);
    -fx-background-color: #10277b;
    -fx-border-radius: 5;
    -fx-font-size: 14;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans";
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}

.button-agree, .button-login, .button-start, .button-stop, .button-video {
    -fx-background-position: left center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-padding: 10 12 10 40;
}

.region-video {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-min-height: 16;
    -fx-min-width: 24;
    -fx-max-height: 16;
    -fx-max-width: 24;
    -fx-shape: "M17.016 10.5l3.984-3.984v10.969l-3.984-3.984v3.516c0 0.563-0.469 0.984-1.031 0.984h-12c-0.563 0-0.984-0.422-0.984-0.984v-10.031c0-0.563 0.422-0.984 0.984-0.984h12c0.563 0 1.031 0.422 1.031 0.984v3.516z";
}


.button-secondary, .button-audio, .button-back, .button-cancel, .button-remark {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-color: #10277b;
    -fx-border-radius: 5;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-font-size: 14;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans";
    -fx-text-fill: #10277b;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(16, 40, 123, 0.2), 0px, 0px, 4px, 4px);
}

.button-audio, .button-back, .button-cancel, .button-remark {
    -fx-background-position: left center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-padding: 10 12 10 40;
}

.region-audio {
    -fx-background-color: #10277b;
    -fx-min-height: 24;
    -fx-min-width: 16;
    -fx-max-height: 24;
    -fx-max-width: 16;
    -fx-shape: "M17.297 11.016h1.688c0 3.422-2.719 6.234-6 6.703v3.281h-1.969v-3.281c-3.281-0.469-6-3.281-6-6.703h1.688c0 3 2.531 5.063 5.297 5.063s5.297-2.063 5.297-5.063zM12 14.016c-1.641 0-3-1.359-3-3v-6c0-1.641 1.359-3 3-3s3 1.359 3 3v6c0 1.641-1.359 3-3 3z";
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: #10277b;
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.label-big-and-bold {
    -fx-text-fill: #10277b;
    -fx-font-size: 24;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.label-small {
    -fx-text-fill: #10277b;
    -fx-font-size: 10;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.pane-background {
    -fx-background-color: #f2f4f8;
}

.pane-white {
    -fx-border-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(16, 40, 123, 0.2), 0px, 0px, 4px, 4px);
}


.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: #f2f4f8;
    -fx-border-color: #3596d2;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0;
    -fx-text-fill: #10277b;
    -fx-font-size: 14;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, #FFFFFF;
    -fx-background-insets: -0.4, 2, -2.8, 5.2;
}


This is getting weird. In another screen, where I haven't replaced the png button icons yet with svg ones that I'm putting on a Region and placing on top of the buttons, this effect of shadowing the buttons themself isn't showing. Although the dropshadow isn't functioning completely proper on this screen either, the main problem seems to be related with the whole replacing png button icons with svg ones on a Region which I happen to be doing simultaneously

Even weirder, when I change the first button on this second page with the svg (on the Region) in place, that button doesn't get the dropshadow over the button, only on the outside (just a gap in between of one row of pixels, which is another problem, but okay, it isn't shadowing the whole button this time). I might be able to find the distinguishing difference between those pages myself later today or tomorrow

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that illustrates the problem you settle on.

Create and post a [mre].

added source code for minimal reproducible example

Just for next time, a [mcve] for a UI issue only needs UI code, it doesn't need SpringBoot, all you need is a JavaFX application class and some CSS.  Making the example minimal makes it easier for people to replicate, diagnose the problem, and answer, which is usually better for you and others who may have the same issue.

The problem arises because your buttons are disabled, and the default style defined in modena.css sets the opacity for disabled items to 0.4. Thus your buttons are partially transparent and you can see the shadow through them.
If you turn off the opacity setting for disabled buttons, e.g. with
.button:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}

it will fix the problem. You probably want some kind of visual clue that the button is disabled, so this is unlikely to be the exact fix you need, but it demonstrates what is causing the issue.

I see. That is indeed probably not the solution I was looking for as I only want the buttons enabled when users have entered data into both textfields. But, now with the svg icons on a Region instead of png's as icon through css I could actually keep the buttons visually enabled and only do something with the color and disable the icons (which I'm already doing). So there could be a workaround ...

Do you understand why, if you set both buttons to enabled, the dropshadow of the white button with the blue border has a 1 pixel gap between the button and the shadow on the bottom side? I actually find it also kinda weird that the blue button is 1 pixel too high (45 instead of 44, take a screen print and zoom in in paint to see it) but it does have the correct shadow of 4 pixels high immediately underneath, where the white button is 44 pixels high as it should be, but with the 4 pixel shadow just a pixel too low ...

@JeroenV Not off the top of my head, but you probably need to carefully go through the default style sheet to understand all that fully. Your probably seeing a border on the button, most likely implemented by a nested background.

I got it working using -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 0, 0; and to get it really nice and smooth I had to do add -fx-background-radius being the same as the -fx-border-radius

"Do you understand why, if you set both buttons to enabled, the drop shadow of the white button with the blue border has a 1-pixel gap between the button and the shadow on the bottom side" -> That is because the default button styling uses multiple backgrounds with insets to create a faux 3D effect for the buttons.  But, you don't want that.  You create your 3D effect using drop shadows instead.   Your change to update the insets and border removes the default styling 3D effect, so only your 3D effect from the drop shadow is visible.

@JeroenV Note pretty much all "borders" styled by modena.css (the default application user agent stylesheet for JavaFX 8+) are actually multiple backgrounds with increasingly larger insets. You'll have to take that into account, such as by setting the insets to 0 (I think -fx-background-insets: 0; should be enough), unless you completely replace modena.css.

I actually fixed this by placing two buttons on top of each other with the exact same dimension and location. The first one in the fxml is enabled, has a white background and no action connected to it and the second one is one line lower in the fxml file and disabled until enough characters are entered, but does have an action. It is a bit of a hack, but I feel like I'm doing that quite often when working with JavaFX ...

Wouldn't it be easier to just override the style for .button:disabled so that it indicates the button is disabled without changing the opacity?

good thinking! Works like a charm :-)

Which is exactly the solution I posted before you posted this one.
